# How to implement firebase email link authentication in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I want to send email link to user's email to authenticate user in my extension. How to automatically detect when the user clicked the link in email?

I've configured up to sending email. But my problem is extension popup still shows login form even after user clicked the link.

I'm using React.

How to automatically provision the access to user after he has clicked the email link?

Comment: I need the same thing. Did you ever get an answer to your question? Some have said it's not possible, without giving reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> How to automatically detect when the user clicked the link in email?

Firebase will log user on the device on which they clicked the link. Even if it's the same device, it'll most probably in a different tab. Easiest thing to do would be using Firebase Realtime Database.

1. When use enters email, send the sign in link and listen on a particular node in relatime database.
2. When use clicks on that link and is redirected to any page after login, update the value that node in RTDB.
3. When the update is received, do the changes required.

However this won't work is user uses the link on a completely different device so a custom solution might be needed.

Comment: How to do it without firebase realtime db?

Comment: @axfg you need a way to emit updates to the tab where user entered the email. RTDB sounds easiest to implement. Other options would be setting up websockets yourself (i.e. your own server)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're working on Firebase email link authentication in a Chrome extension. I recently published a blog post that walks through this exact process. It covers project setup, the authentication flow, and a detailed breakdown of each step, complete with code snippets.

I think it would be a great resource for you and help clear up any issues you're encountering. You can find the post [here](https://younessssssss.github.io/chrome/extension/firebase/authentication/2023/05/28/chrome-extension-guide-firebase-authentication-with-email-links.html). Hope it helps, and feel free to ask any follow-up questions!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34443911)